# libusb on lollipop - fails to get devices list

Tags: android, security, android-5.0-lollipop, libusb, android-5.1.1-lollipop

Few days ago i've tested my app on Android Lollipop and it stops working. After debugging i've found libsub fails to get devices list:

```
struct libusb_device **devs;
int devs_count = libusb_get_device_list(ctx, &devs);
```

I've continues to dig the sources and found the next failure (linux_usbfs.c):

```
DIR *buses = opendir(usbfs_path); // '/dev/bus/usb', correct
struct discovered_devs *discdevs = *_discdevs;
int r = 0;

if (!buses) {
    usbi_err(ctx, "opendir buses failed errno=%d", errno);
    return LIBUSB_ERROR_IO; // my case!
}
```

usbfs_path is correct (`/dev/bus/usb`) and my device is `/dev/bus/usb/003/002`.

How can i work with usb device using libusb in Android Lollipop?

Previously i've iterated over devices, found my device using PID and VID, requested it's endpoints and worked as usual. Now i can't get `struct libusb_device **devs;` using `libusb_get_device_list` and this stops everything. What can i do having device path and opened connection file descriptor from android?

PS. testing on Nexus 9 with Android 5.1.1

PPS. I can't use either `libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid` as it requests devices list too:

```
DEFAULT_VISIBILITY
libusb_device_handle * LIBUSB_CALL libusb_open_device_with_vid_pid(
libusb_context *ctx, uint16_t vendor_id, uint16_t product_id)
{
    struct libusb_device **devs;
    struct libusb_device *found = NULL;
    struct libusb_device *dev;
    struct libusb_device_handle *handle = NULL;
    size_t i = 0;
    int r;

    if (libusb_get_device_list(ctx, &devs) < 0)
        return NULL;
```

Comment: What are you trying to do by listing the devices with libsub? Did you have to compile libusb with the ndk first?

Comment: i'm trying to get libusb_device* list to use for interaction. Is there any opportunity to interact with usb device without getting list?

Comment: What is wrong with a list? What ae you asking? Can you retrieve data from the usbs?

Comment: the list is not returned as `usbfs_get_device_list()` in `os\linux_usbfs` fails on line `opendir()`

Comment: I do not know your end goal. You want just get a list of USB devices connected to your Android device?

Comment: i send data and receive data over usb from usb device. for this i request device list, find my device using PID/VID, find right endpoints and communicate with it. Nothing special. The problem is that usb_get_device_list() fails